# C++ Reconnect TCP Server to Client after Client restart

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I want to implement a 'flexible' TCP connection where I can randomly shutdown and restart both the Server and the Client. The other one should then automatically detect the shutdown and enter try to reconnect. I successfully implemented this s.t. I can shutdown and restart the server. The client discovers the shutdown (via `recv(...) == 0`) and then closes the connection (it therefore closes the sockets `close(this->sockfd_)` and `close(this->newsockfd_)`).

Unfortunately I am not able to get this working the other way around. I initialize the server (using the class constructor) the following way:

```
tcpServer::tcpServer(int _port) {
  this->sockfd_ = -1;
  this->port_ = _port;
  this->connected_ = false;
  if ((this->sockfd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    this->dieWithError("ERROR opening Socket");
  else
    printf("-> Port %d: Socket opened\n", this->port_);
  // get rid of "address already in use" error message
  int yes = 1;
  setsockopt(this->sockfd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
  /* assign values to the fields of struct sockaddr_in */
  bzero((char *) &this->serv_addr_, sizeof(this->serv_addr_));
  this->serv_addr_.sin_family = AF_INET;
  this->serv_addr_.sin_port = htons(this->port_);
  this->serv_addr_.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  /* bind the socket to an address */
  if (bind(this->sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &this->serv_addr_, sizeof(this->serv_addr_)) < 0) {
    printf("-> Port %d:", this->port_);
    this->dieWithError("ERROR on binding");
  }
  printf("-> Binding successful. Start TCP client in new terminal\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  /* listen for connections and accept a connection */
  listen(this->sockfd_, 5);
  this->clilen_ = sizeof(this->cli_addr_);
  if ((this->newsockfd_ = accept(this->sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &this->cli_addr_, &this->clilen_)) < 0)
    this->dieWithError("Error on accept");
  else {
    printf("-> Connection established\n");
    this->connected_ = true;
  }
}
```

So once the server detects that the connection is closed, it enters a loop where it tries to reconnect using the following code:

```
void tcpServer::connect() {
  if (this->sockfd_ == -1) {
    /* create socket */
    if ((this->sockfd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        this->dieWithError("ERROR opening Socket");
    else
        printf("-> Port %d: Socket opened\n", this->port_);
    // get rid of "address already in use" error message
    int reuse_address = 1;
    setsockopt(this->sockfd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_address, sizeof(int));
    /* listen for connections and accept a connection */
    listen(this->sockfd_, 5);
    this->clilen_ = sizeof(this->cli_addr_);
    if ((this->newsockfd_ = accept(this->sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &this->cli_addr_, &this->clilen_)) < 0)
        this->dieWithError("Error on accept");
    else {
        printf("-> Connection established\n");
        this->connected_ = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Some simple debugging output tells me that in the reconnect-mode, the server gets stuck in the 
`accept(this->sockfd_, (struct sockaddr *) &this->cli_addr_, &this->clilen_)` call. Another observation I made is that the client does not shut down properly (via `ctrl-c`), i.e., it gets stuck in a loop somewhere and does not properly close the connection.

Since I am a total beginner with the TCP stuff, I would be very happy if someone could point me to the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: TLDR. Try to make your question/code example as minimal as possible.

Comment: Clearly your second observation is the direct result of the first. You need to debug the client and check what prevents it from shutting down gracefully.